# PowerShell Retrieving value of TextBox from another thread (WPF)

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, powershell, runspace

I'm looking to be able to get the text from my textbox (folderDialogTextBox.Text), I am able to successfully set the text using the dispatcher, but oddly enough I cannot read the current value of the text.

When running  **$syncHash** from the console, I get:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
folderDialogTextBox            System.Windows.Controls.TextBox: Please select Browse to search for a directory
```

so I can see that I do have some able to see the value "Please select Browse", yet when I run the following command below, I can set the value:

```
$Global:syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{$Global:Synchash.folderDialogTextBox.Text = "Hello"},"Normal")
```

Yet, when I try to retrieve the value here, I don't get anything back

```
$Global:syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{$Global:Synchash.folderDialogTextBox.Text},"Normal")
```

**Below is the full code with the xml**

Thanks for the assistance!

```
$Global:syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"         
$newRunspace.Open()
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash",$syncHash)

$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({   

$inputXML = $xaml = @"
    <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    Title="Test" Height="500" Width="827" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" MinHeight="300" >



<Grid Name="progressBar">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="458*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="292*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="77*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RichTextBox Name="outputTextBox"   Margin="186,55,10,19" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsReadOnly="True" AcceptsTab="True" >
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text=""/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
    <UniformGrid Background="#FF0291DC" Rows="3" Columns="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="171">
    </UniformGrid>
    <ProgressBar Height="10" Margin="186,0,10,4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsIndeterminate="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    <TextBox Name="folderDialogTextBox" Margin="186,10,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please select Browse to search for a directory" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="18"/>
    <CheckBox Name="recursiveButton" Content="Perform Recursive Search (All subfolders)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="186,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="15" Width="236"/>
    <Button Name="browseButton" Content="Browse" Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="57" Grid.Column="2" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>




</Grid>


</Window>
"@
[xml]$Global:xmlWPF = $inputXML
#Add WPF and Windows Forms assemblies
try{
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework,WindowsBase,system.windows.forms
} catch {
Throw “Failed to load Windows Presentation Framework assemblies.”
}


$Global:syncHash.Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((new-object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xmlWPF))

[xml]$XAML = $xmlWPF

$xmlWPF.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]") | %{
$Global:synchash.Add($_.Name,$Global:syncHash.Window.FindName($_.Name) )}



$SB = {

$textboxvalue = $Global:syncHash.folderDialogTextBox.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{$Global:Synchash.folderDialogTextBox.Text},"Normal")
$Global:syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{$Global:Synchash.outputTextBox.AppendText("textboxvalue = $textboxvalue`r")},"Normal")

}


$Global:syncHash.browseButton.add_click({Start-Runspace $SB})

$Global:syncHash.Window.ShowDialog() | out-null      
})
$psCmd.Runspace = $newRunspace
$data = $psCmd.BeginInvoke()
start-sleep -Milliseconds 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I came across it looking for an answer myself.

From testing, I've found that you have to set a value on your synchronized hashtable (or another variable both threads would have access to) from within the dispatcher. Using the dispatcher doesn't pass the result back to the calling thread. So in your example:

```
$Global:synchash.folderDialogTextBox.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{$Global:synchash.textBoxText = $Global:synchash.folderDialogTextBox.Text}, "Normal")
$Global:synchash.textBoxText #contains the text value of folderDialogTextBox
```

I hope this helps anyone else who'd be looking.